# Can't using Parse + Facebook authentification

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I have tried to use parse + facebook auth. I am following a tutorial and i got some error like that when i compiled my project on the file : PFFacebookAuthentificationProvider.h/m

```
/Users/.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:17:26: error: expected parameter declarator
@class BFTask PF_GENERIC(__covariant BFGenericType);
                     ^
/Users/Y.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:17:26: error: expected ')'
/Users/.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:17:25: note: to match this '('
@class BFTask PF_GENERIC(__covariant BFGenericType);
                    ^
/Users/.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:17:15: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
@class BFTask PF_GENERIC(__covariant BFGenericType);
          ^
/Users/.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:43:4: error: expected a type
 - (BFTask *)authenticateAsyncWithReadPermissions:(nullable NSArray PF_GENERIC(NSString *) *)readPermissions
^/Users/.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:43:51: error: nullability specifier 'nullable' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'NSArray'
- (BFTask *)authenticateAsyncWithReadPermissions:(nullable NSArray PF_GENERIC(NSString *) *)readPermissions
                                              ^
/Users/.../Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:43:68: error: expected ')'
- (BFTask *)authenticateAsyncWithReadPermissions:(nullable NSArray PF_GENERIC(NSString *) *)readPermissions
```

20 errors.
Here my podfile :

```
platform :ios, '8.1'

xcodeproj 'Test'

target :Test, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'ParseUI'
    pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue. The way I fixed it was going back one version of parse...

`pod 'Parse', '~>1.11.0'`

I think the issue is related to ParseFacebookUtilsV4 Pod not updating to latest version. Either way, that should get you back up and running for now.

Comment: Thx a lot, fixed issue. But it s strange cause i was on 1.12 version

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue. It seems Parse 1.12.0 is just not ready for FB integration. I noticed the PFSubclassing and PFObject classes changed colors (compiler) after updating to Parse 1.12.0 using cocoapods. I suppose they're finally written in swift but after the update, other depending libraries such as ParseFacebookUtilsV4 started complaining because I believe they still have objective-c code. Anyway, downgrading back to Parse 1.11.0 got rid of tons of errors I was seeing and had no idea why. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Check for your plist for the right permissions.

Comment: can you be more explicit please ?